# change list elements

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python List Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)

```
result=[range(3)]*2
for i in range(len(result)):
    result[i][2]=4*i
print result
```

I would expected `[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 4]]`

Why do I get `[[0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4]]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `[range(3)] * 2`, it makes a list with two references to *the same* list inside, so modifying `result[0]` and `result[1]` each modify both.

Use `[range(3) for i in range(2)]` to make a list with two different results of `range(3)` in it.

Comment: your suggestion works very well. Thank you! why would [range(3)]*2 make a list with two references to the same list, and modify each will modify both? just doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

- List "result" is: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
- Your iteration is: "for i in range(len(result))"
- len(result) is: 2
- range(2) is: [0,1]

meaning:

first time:
result[0][2]=4*0

second time:
result[1][2]=4*1

which gives you the result [[0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4]]

This is what is doing step by step.

If you add a "break" to the iteration you see the result is [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]

The "result" list works by reference. When it is called, it is pointing to the same object.

Comment: then why in the output result[0][2]=4?

Comment: You should check out this post by Jeff Knupp http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/