# How to use a array of heaps in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap

I need to create and use n heaps, I am trying to use heapq and is trying to push elements into a list of lists, where each element is to be considered a seperate heap. But its behaving weirdly. I just wanna push the elements 6 and 7 into my 3rd heap. but its getting pushed into all my heaps. any way out of this??

```
>>> test
[[], [], [], []]
>>> 
>>> heappush(test[2],6)
>>> heappush(test[2],7)
>>> test
[[6, 7], [6, 7], [6, 7], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python List Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)

Comment: You should really show the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have created `test` something like this:

```
>>> from heapq import heappush
>>> test = [[]] * 4
>>>
>>> heappush(test[2],6)
>>> heappush(test[2],7)
>>> test
[[6, 7], [6, 7], [6, 7], [6, 7]]
```

This creates four references to the *same* list object. Use a list comprehension to make four distinct lists:

```
>>> test = [[] for _ in range(4)]
>>> heappush(test[2],6)
>>> heappush(test[2],7)
>>> test
[[], [], [6, 7], []]
```

Comment: I love it how you must've answered this question at least 5 times in the past few days.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same heap instance for all the heaps. Are you perhaps doing something like this?

```
test = [ [] * 4]
```

You need to create four distinct heaps instead. Exactly how depends on what you are doing now.