# python list with fixed number of elements

Tags: python, list

I want to create a fixed size list of size 6 of tuples in Python. Note that in the code below i am always re-initializing the values in the outer for loop in order to reset the previously created list which was already added to globalList. Here is a snippet:

```
for i,j in dictCaseId.iteritems():
    listItems=[None]*6
    for x,y in j:
        if x=='cond':
            tuppo = y
            listItems.insert(0,tuppo)
        if x=='act':
            tuppo = y
            listItems.insert(1,tuppo)
        if x=='correc':
            tuppo = y
            listItems.insert(2,tuppo)
            ...
            ...
    globalList.append(listItems)
```

But when I try to run the above (snippet only shown above) it increases the list size. I mean, stuff gets added but I also see the list contains more number of elements. I dont want my list size to increase and my list is a list of 6 tuples.

For example:

```
Initially: [None,None,None,None,None,None]
What I desire: [Mark,None,Jon,None,None,None]
What I get: [Mark,None,Jon,None,None,None,None,None]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of inserting you should assign those values. `list.insert` inserts a new element at the index passed to it, so length of list increases by 1 after each insert operation.
On the other hand assignment modifies the value at a particular index, so length remains constant.

```
for i,j in dictCaseId.iteritems():
    listItems=[None]*6
    for x,y in j:
        if x=='cond':
            tuppo = y
            listItems[0]=tuppo
        if x=='act':
            tuppo = y
            listItems[1]=tuppo
        if x=='correc':
            tuppo = y
            listItems[2]=tuppo
```

Example:

```
>>> lis = [None]*6
>>> lis[1] = "foo"   #change the 2nd element
>>> lis[4] = "bar"   #change the fifth element
>>> lis
[None, 'foo', None, None, 'bar', None]
```

**Update:**

```
>>> lis = [[] for _ in xrange(6)] # don't use  [[]]*6
>>> lis[1].append("foo")
>>> lis[4].append("bar")
>>> lis[1].append("py")
>>> lis
[[], ['foo', 'py'], [], [], ['bar'], []]
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini. That works. However my list is a list of tuples. What I mean is it has 6 elements and each element can be a tuple. But when I insert like above it will rewrite the previously inserted element. So how can I insert a tuple. For example I need [(foo,bar),None,bar,None,None,None]

Comment: @Yavar you may have to use a list of lists then instead of lists of None, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy! That's perfect. I am a C++ coder new to Python, learning on the job. That really helped me!! Accepted with a +1 :)

Comment: @Yavar You're welcome. Make sure you don't use something like this : `[[]]*6`. Reason : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index

Answer (score 3):

[Ashwini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16415311/1907098) fixes your main issue, however I will make a suggestion here.

Because (from what you have shown us) you are simply assigning an element to a specific index based on a condition, it would be better to do something like this:

```
for i, j in dictCaseId.iteritems():
    listItems = [None] * 6
    lst = ['cond', 'act', 'correc', ...]
    for x, y in j:
        idx = lst.index(x)
        listItems[idx] = y
    globalList.append(listItems)
```

Or with a list of lists:

```
for i, j in dictCaseId.iteritems():
    listItems = [[] for _ in xrange(6)]
    lst = ['cond', 'act', 'correc', ...]
    for x, y in j:
        idx = lst.index(x)
        listItems[idx].append(y)
    globalList.append(listItems)
```

This allows each of the conditions to be dealt with in one go, and it condenses your code significantly.

Comment: Thanks Volatility, that does help, indeed a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `listItems.insert(0, tuppo)`, do `listItems[0] = tuppo` etc.

Answer (score 1):

thats becauce you insert the names indestead of changing the value.
do like this indstead

```
for i,j in dictCaseId.iteritems():
    listItems=[None]*6
    for x,y in j:
        if x=='cond':
            tuppo = y
            listItems[0] = tuppo
        if x=='act':
            tuppo = y
            listItems[1] = tuppo
        if x=='correc':
            tuppo = y
            listItems[2] = tuppo                ...
            ...
    globalList.append(listItems)
```