# Setting a Value in a Nested Python List Automatically Iterates

Tags: python, iteration, nested-lists

I have a python list, created by `model = [[[[0,0,0,0]]*4]*15]*5`, which is a list that looks like this (without the brevity dots): `model = [[[[0,0,0,0],...[0,0,0,0]]...[[0,0,0,0],...[0,0,0,0]]]...[[[0,0,0,0],...[0,0,0,0]]...[[0,0,0,0],...[0,0,0,0]]]]`. The problem is that when I try to set one of the zeros to some other value using

`def setLED(model,boardid,chipid,tankid,ledid,value):
     model[boardid][chipid][tankid][ledid]=value`

every list of 4 zeros gets set the same. i.e. if I tried to use setLED(model,0,0,0,0,255), the first value in every list of 4 zeros would be 255. The intended result is that only the first list of 4 zeros, (i.e. model[0][0][0][0]), would be changed. I don't think there is a way to attach files, but if anyone needs it, I can post the full contents of the list.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can figure out why this is happening.

EDIT: This is a duplicate of [Nested List Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an array of arrays like this:

```
[[0]]*n
```

you are creating an array holding n references to the same array. You need to add new arrays in another manner. One way to do this would be to use list comprehensions, i.e.

```
[[[ [0,0,0,0] for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(15)] for _ in range(5)]
```

which does create new arrays instead of reusing references.

Comment: Any recommendations for the best way to make such a structure without typing it? I think numpy may be the best option, but I haven't figured that out yet.