# making an array of sets in python

Tags: python, set

I am having trouble with a list of sets and I think it is because I initialized it wrong, is this a valid way to initialize and add to a list of 5000 sets?

```
sets = [set()]*5000
i = 0
for each in f:
    line = each.split()
    if (some statement):
        i = line[1]

    else:
        sets[i].add(line[0])
```

any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python List Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)

Comment: `[set() for _ in xrange(5000)]`

Comment: There is a typo in the `for set in sets:` statement.

Comment: `for each in f`... what's `f`? An open file?

Answer (score 28):

You are storing a copy of reference to a single set in each of your list indices. So, modifying one will change the others too.

To create a list of multiple sets, you can use list comprehension:

```
sets = [set() for _ in xrange(5000)]
```

Comment: xrange? → maybe range

Comment: xrange is used in older version of python .python3 uses range()

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
>>> lotsosets=[set() for i in range(5)]
>>> lotsosets
[set([]), set([]), set([]), set([]), set([])]
>>> lotsosets[0].add('see me?')
>>> lotsosets
[set(['see me?']), set([]), set([]), set([]), set([])]
>>> lotsosets[1].add('imma here too')
>>> lotsosets
[set(['see me?']), set(['imma here too']), set([]), set([]), set([])]
```

You should only use the form `[x]*5000` if `x` is something immutable:

```
>>> li=[None]*5
>>> li
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> li[0]=0
>>> li
[0, None, None, None, None]
>>> li[1]=1
>>> li
[0, 1, None, None, None]
```

Or if having multiple references to a single item, like an iterator, produces desired behavior:

```
>>> [iter('abc')]*3
[<iterator object at 0x100498410>, 
 <iterator object at 0x100498410>, 
 <iterator object at 0x100498410>]   # 3 references to the SAME object
```

Note the repeated reference to the same iterator which then produces a desired behavior with zip:

```
>>> zip(*[iter('abcdef')]*3)
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

Or a subset of a longer iterator:

```
>>> [next(x) for x in [iter('abcdef')]*3]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Whereas something like `[list()]*5` is probably not producing what is intended:

```
>>> li=[list()]*5
>>> li
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> li[0].append('whoa')
>>> li
[['whoa'], ['whoa'], ['whoa'], ['whoa'], ['whoa']]
```