# Different Dictionaries sharing the same instance

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some 7 dictionaries in a program whose data is fetched using ETREE , the problem is that python does not create a separate dict instance for each dict as shown in the output  , whenever I print any of these dicts I get the same output which is a large dictionary having a union of all data.

```
 tr_dict,tr_text,exp_dict,exp_text,top_dict,top_text,times=[{}]*7 #create n empty dictionaries
    for tr in transcript:
        trtext = tr.find('TATION/ANNOTATION_VALUE').text
        tr_time_ref = tr.find('TATION').attrib['TIME_SLOT_REF1']
        tr_ann_ref = tr.find('ATION').attrib['ANNOTATION_ID']

        tr_dict[tr_ann_ref] =  tr_time_ref
        tr_text[tr_time_ref]=trtext

...
```

Output:

```
[Dbg]>>> exp_dict is exp_text
True
[Dbg]>>> tr_dict is tr_text
True
[Dbg]>>> tr_dict is exp_dict
True
```

Ofcourse I dont want this to happen , I want python to create and use a seperate dict for each.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python List Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)

Comment: Have you considered tr_dict = {}, tr_text = {}, etc.?

Comment: @ecatmur thanks for pointing out the real reason(pass by reference) , this shortcut cost me time :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
[{}] * 7
```

Do this instead:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Explanation: the first line will create *one* dictionary and copy seven references to it in the list, whereas the second line creates seven different dictionaries - and that's what you want to do. Alternatively, as stated in the comments, this will also work:

```
[{} for _ in range(7)]
```

Comment: Or `[{} for _ in range(7)]`, which isn't shorter but makes counting the dictionaries easier.