# Where goes wrong in this list manipulation?

Tags: python

I am manipulating with the lists in Python.

```
In [52]: myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
In [54]: c=[[]]*10

In [55]: for i, elem1 in enumerate(myList):
   ....:     b = [elem1 + elem2 for elem2 in range(10)]
   ....:     minSum, minSumIndex= min((val, idx) for (idx, val) in enumerate(b))
   ....:     c[minSumIndex].append(elem1)
```

I am **expecting** all the elements in `myList` to be appended to `c[0]`, since `elem1+1` always gives the smallest sum.

```
print c[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print c[1]
[]

print c[2]
[]

...
```

**However, I ended up with this:**

```
In [56]: shape(c)
Out[56]: (10, 5)

In [57]: print c[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [58]: print c[1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [59]: print c[2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [60]: print c[3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [61]: print c[4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [62]: print c[5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Where went wrong?

Comment: Dup: [Python List Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of your confusion is on this line

```
c=[[]]*10
```

Here you are creating a list of ten references to the same (initially empty) list. Thus as you append to the list in `c[0]` later on, you are also appending to every other list in `c`. Try

```
c = [ [] for _ in range(10) ]
```

This will create a new list 10 ten times, so you won't have the same referencing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lists in `c` are all the same object.
You need to do at least:

```
c = [[] for i in xrange(10)]
```