# Appending to nested list inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Consider this example:

```
>>> result = [[]] * 8
>>> result
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> result[0]
[]
>>> result[0].append("foo")
>>> result  # wtf? expected result: [['foo'], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo']]
```

I'm terribly confused by this. Maybe I don't understand how `append` is expected to be used. How would I append to the `i`th nested listed inside a list?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427735/where-goes-wrong-in-this-list-manipulation/19427770#19427770) from earlier today.

Comment: You are duplicating references to the same list. `result[0]` is the same object as `result[1]`, `result[2]`, etc.

Comment: Ah... I see. Pretty subtle. Thanks, voted to close my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

That's because, by doing this:

```
result = [[]] * 8
```

you make 8 *copies* of the *same* list.  Your code should be:

```
>>> result = [[] for _ in xrange(8)]
>>> result
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> result[0]
[]
>>> result[0].append("foo")
>>> result
[['foo'], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>>
```

As a proof, consider this:

```
>>> lst = [[]] * 2
>>> lst
[[], []]
>>> id(lst[0])
28406048
>>> id(lst[1])
28406048
>>>
```

Notice that the id's of the lists are the same where as here:

```
>>> lst = [[] for _ in xrange(2)]
>>> lst
[[], []]
>>> id(lst[0])
28408408
>>> id(lst[1])
28418096
>>>
```

they are different.